# misplaced qed symbol after displaymath inside item of inline list

Tags: lists, theorems, enumitem, ntheorem, thmtools

My problem involes a qed symbol which appears too early.
My observations are that it happens after a displaymath inside an item of an unboxed inline list.
All of this seems to be necessary to produce the error.

The packages involved are `ntheorem`, `thmtools` and `enumitem`.

If I compile this code with `lualatex` using `TeXLive 2011`.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\PassOptionsToPackage{thmmarks}{ntheorem}
\PassOptionsToPackage{inline}{enumitem}

\usepackage{amsmath,MnSymbol}
\usepackage{ntheorem,thmtools}
\usepackage{
    enumitem,
}

\declaretheoremstyle[qed={\quad\blacksquare}]{plain}
\declaretheorem[style=plain,numbered=no,name=Proof]{proof}%

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
  \begin{enumerate*}[mode=unboxed]
    \[a\]
    Still proof.
  \end{enumerate*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

the output becomes:

[image: qed symbol is placed before end of proof]

The symbol is placed correctly if the `enumerate*` environment isn't used or if `$$` or `\begin{displaymath` and `\end{displaymath}` is used to mark displaymath mode instead of `\[` and `\]`.

Clearly, the qed symbol should be at the end of the proof after “Still proof.” – What am I doing wrong? Couldn't find anything so far.

Comment: I also encountered similiar misplacements of the qed symbol in other contexts, but I couldn't reproduce them so far. If I find further such reproduceable misplacements, I'll post them, too.

Comment: this problem doesn't occur with `amsthm`.  i'm not a user of `ntheorem`, so you may have other reasons for using it.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I use it to define certain theoremstyles. Maybe I can switch. But this, of course, still wouldn't really _solve_ this particular problem.

Comment: in the ams author faq, there's [a question](http://www.ams.org/faq?faq_id=212&hide_group=1) that deals with qed and other symbols in "nonstandard" places in and out of proofs, by reference to a linked example file.  it's specific to `amsthm`, but maybe it would give you some ideas.  sorry i can't help with `ntheorem`.

Comment: `ntheorem` seems to add the `\qed` to the last display mode equation. So, a __hackish__ solution would be to end the proof with `\vspace{-\belowdisplayskip}\[\]`.

Comment: This seems a bug of `ntheorem` that should be reported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per my earlier comment `ntheorem` seems to add the `\qed` to the very last display mode equation.  So a *hack* is to to end a proof with

```
\vspace{-\belowdisplayskip}\[\]
```

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\PassOptionsToPackage{thmmarks}{ntheorem}
\PassOptionsToPackage{inline}{enumitem}

\usepackage{amsmath,MnSymbol}
\usepackage{ntheorem,thmtools}
\usepackage{
    enumitem,
}

\declaretheoremstyle[qed={\quad\blacksquare}]{plain}
\declaretheorem[style=plain,numbered=no,name=Proof]{proof}%

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
  \begin{enumerate*}[mode=unboxed]
    \[a\]
    Still proof.
  \end{enumerate*}
  \vspace{-\belowdisplayskip}\[\]
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I accepted the answer even though it is – as you said yourself – merely a *hackish* solution. I personally just switched to using the `displaymath`-environment. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is due to the use of the enumitem package.

Ntheorem supports a finite set of standard LaTeX environments. The algorithm consists of modifications to these environments to trace where the end mark belongs (for the implementation, see its documentation).

As there are dozens of packages that define own environments, it is not
possible to support all of them.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you considering to register your account?